# Powerline Adapter Into Cheater Plug

Tags: electrical, wiring, data-wiring, wifi

We live in a pretty old house that is brick and plaster all over the first floor where our AT&T Uverse wireless router is set up. Although we have fiber internet, we get very poor wifi speeds in our basement. I purchased [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0136Q9QJK) powerline adapter to overcome this issue.

However, our router is also on the floor that doesn't have any three-prong outlets, so I am using [cheater plugs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZYS8MP). (**Note**, I have tested the outlets with the cheaters on and I am getting a good ground.) My question is will I have issues if I plug my powerline adapter into a cheater plug? I have read that using power strips/surge protectors can result in adverse signal effects but I haven't found anything conclusive about cheater plugs.

Thank you.

Comment: If your grounds are good, fit grounded outlets.   Usually, if it was that easy, it would've been done already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapters that you purchased should be unaffected by the so called "cheaters".

Power strips and surge protectors include basic electronic components that can cause noise or other interference to the powerline adapters, but the basic two-prong adapter is just a few sicks of metal.

Also, the adapters you chose use the "AV1000" standard.  That, along with AV500 and the newer AV2 HomePlugs only use two wires for communication.  The newest HomePlug, AV2 MIMO, makes use of the grounding conductor for better reliability and faster speeds.

http://www.homeplug.org/explore-homeplug/faq-consumers/#AV2a

You should be fine.  I haven't used any of the newer Poweline/HomePlug adapters, but the older ones that I used never delivered anywhere near the speed they promised, so keep that in mind.  Maybe they are better now, but buy the books at least, your two conductor solution shouldn't be a problem.